# Get success status from Find -delete

Tags: bash, find

Wondering how I get success code when using the `Find -delete` command. Want to know what files it has removed and if there were any errors. I want to save this information in a log file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as noted in `man find`, the `-delete` action returns true if the file is successfully deleted so can be used like any other test

> ```
>    -delete
>           Delete files; true if removal succeeded.
> ```

So for example you can `-print` only those files that are deleted ex. given

```
$ find . -name 'hostname*'
./otherdir/hostname3
./otherdir/hostname2
./otherdir/hostname1
./hostname7
./hostname5
./hostname6
```

then

```
$ find . -name 'hostname*' -delete -print >deleted 2>not_deleted
```

results in

```
$ head *deleted
==> deleted <==
./hostname7
./hostname5
./hostname6

==> not_deleted <==
find: cannot delete ‘./otherdir/hostname3’: Permission denied
find: cannot delete ‘./otherdir/hostname2’: Permission denied
find: cannot delete ‘./otherdir/hostname1’: Permission denied
```